# Variadic templates and multiple inheritance in c++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, variadic-templates

i'm trying to achieve something like this:

I have a templated base class which i want to inherit dynamically

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class fooBase
{
public:
    fooBase(){};
    ~fooBase(){};
};
```

desired method: (something like this, not really sure how to do it)

```
template <typename... Interfaces>
class foo : public Interfaces...
{
public:
    foo();
    ~foo();
}
```

and my goal is to have the foo class act like this:

second method:

```
class foo()
    : public fooBase<uint8_t, float>
    , public fooBase<uint16_t, bool>
    , public fooBase<uint32_t, int>
    // and the list could go on
{
    foo();
    ~foo();
}
```

with the second method the problem is that if i instantiate an foo object, it will inherit all the time those 3 base classes, i want to make it more generally and when instantiate a foo object, give it with variadic templates the parameters for the base classes, so that i can use the foo class for other types(maybe will inherit just one base class, maybe five)

Thank you

example for instantiating foo

```
foo<<uint8_t, float>, <uint16_t, bool>, <uint32_t, int>, /* and the list could go on and on */> instance
```

Comment: It looks like something similar was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269603/variadic-template-based-multiple-inheritance-for-two-interacting-classes).

Comment: Can you post an example of how you would like to instantiate `foo`?

Comment: You want `foo<int,char,float,double>` to expand into `foo : fooBase<int,char>, fooBase<float,double>` ?

Comment: sure, i want to instantiate it like this:

foo instance<<uint8_t, float>, <uint16_t, bool>, <uint32_t, int>, /* and the list could go on and on */>

Comment: @mihaipop add the example to the question itself with the exact syntax you want to use

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki yes you are right, something like that

Comment: added to the question @PiotrSkotnicki

Comment: it doesn't make much sense with [this syntax](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10abcc98ca8f9914)

Comment: The design of the inteface like this with multiple inheritance from same template class seems strange (and weird) to me. You can easily run into problems with member function when you use same time in that pair A or B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try recursive variadic templates, taking 2 arguments at a time to add a derivation from fooBase.

It could be something like:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class fooBase
{
public:
    fooBase(){};
    ~fooBase(){};
};

template<typename A, typename B, typename ... C>
class foo: public fooBase<A, B>, public foo<C ...> {
};

// termination version by partial specialization
template<typename A, typename B>
class foo<A, B>: public fooBase<A, B> {
};
```

You can then declare:

```
foo<uint8_t, float, uint16_t, bool, uint32_t, int> bar;
```

and bar will be a subobject of `fooBase<uint8_t, float>`, `fooBase<uint16_t, bool>` and `fooBase<uint32_t, int>`

Answer (score 5):

Change foo to someting similar to this:

```
template<typename... Interfaces>
class foo : public Interfaces... {
  public:
    foo(Interfaces... ifaces) : Interfaces(ifaces)... {}

  };
```