# define a class `MultiInherit<MyTuple<X1,X2,...>>` to inherit from `X1,X2,...`

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

How to define a class `MultiInherit<MyTuple<X1,X2,...>>` to inherit from `X1,X2,...` ?
I want to pass `MyTuple<X1,X2,...>` around to compose a new object type.

```
template <class... Xs> class MyTuple{};
template <class MyTupleXs> class MultiInherit : public All_Xs_in_MyTupleXs { //??

};
```

Here is its usage and [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d374bc81ae81683a) (uncompilable):-

```
class B{public: int b;};
class C{public: int c;};
class BC : public MultiInherit<MyTuple<B,C>> {
    public: void testCompile(){
        this->b=this->c;   
    }
};
int main(){
}
```

### Attempt 1

Below is the closest to what I wanted.
If I get raw-types (e.g. `B,C`) as template argumant rather than `MyTuple<B,C>`, it would be easy :-
([MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8f7c4258eb0ddea), compilable)

```
template <class... Xs> class MultiInherit : public Xs... { 
};
class B{public: int b;};
class C{public: int c;};
class BC : public MultiInherit<B,C> {
    public: void testCompile(){
        this->b=this->c;   
    }
};
```

Reference: [Variadic templates and multiple inheritance in c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840960/variadic-templates-and-multiple-inheritance-in-c11)
This doesn't solve.      I want to pass an encapsulated type `MyTuple<B,C>`, not the `B,C`.

### Attempt 2

I thought about adding a new variadic typedef `MyXs` in `MyTuple`:-

```
template <class... Xs> class MyTuple{
   public: using MyXs=Xs...;    
};
template <class MyTupleXs> class MultiInherit : public MyTupleXs::MyXs { 
};
```

Nevertheless, it seems to me that the language has no such feature.

(I am new to variadic template.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Simple answer

You have to [create a template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) of `MultiInherit`. Let's look at the base case of `MultiInherit`:

```
template<class... Xs> 
class MultiInherit : public Xs... {
    // Stuff
};
```

Here, we take a bunch of types and inherit from them. But we can use a template specialization to unpack tuples:

```
// Specialization on MyTuple
template<class... Xs> 
class MultiInherit<MyTuple<Xs...>> : public Xs... {
     // Stuff
};
```

This allows you to do what you want. Given a `MyTuple`, you have a `MultiInherit` class that inherits from all the members.

#### More general case

**Defining a type list.** If you want to do things more generally, it'll be useful to do them based on templates representing type lists. We can define a template to represent a type list:

```
template<class...>
struct TypeList {};
```

**Concatenating type lists.** We can define more templates to concatenate type lists. `ConcatLists` is a function that takes two type lists, and returns a `TypeList` that concatenates them:

```
template<class... Xs, class... Ys>
TypeList<Xs..., Ys...> ConcatLists(TypeList<Xs...>, TypeList<Ys...>) {
    return {}; 
}
```

We can use that to define a `concat_t` that does that automatically:

```
template<class TypeListA, class TypeListB>
using concat_t = decltype(ConcatLists(TypeListA{}, TypeListB{}));
```

**Substituting `MultiInherit` for `TypeList`.** We can also substitute one type for another type using template specializations.

```
// Base case
template<template<class...> class Replacement, class List>
struct SubstituteList;

template<
    template<class...> class Replacement, 
    template<class...> class Original,
    class... Xs>
struct SubstituteList<Replacement, Original<Xs...>> {
    using type = Replacement<Xs...>;
};

template<template<class...> class Replacement, class List>
using substitute_list_t = typename SubstituteList<Replacement, List>::type;
```

This means that you can take a `TypeList` and replace it with a `MultiInherit`:

```
template<class ListOfTypes>
using MultiInheritFromTypeList = substitute_list_t<MultiInherit, ListOfTypes>;
```

**Example usage.** If you want to convert a `TypeList` to a `MultiInherit`:

```
using T1 = TypeList<int, char, bool>;
// T2 is MultiInherit<int, char, bool>;
using T2 = MultiInheritFromTypeList<T1>;
```

**Example with concat.** Or, if you want to concat multiple `TypeList`s and convert it to a `MultiInherit`:

```
using T1 = TypeList<int, char, bool>;
using T2 = TypeList<double, float>;
// T3 is MuliInherit<int, char, bool, double, float>
using T3 = MultiInheritFromTypeList<concat_t<T1, T2>>;
```

Comment: I am curious. How to hide the base case?

Comment: @javaLover you can simply leave the primary template undefined, i.e., just provide a declaration for `template <class... Xs> class MultiInherit;` and provide a definition only for the partial specialization. If anyone were then to use `MultiInherit` with anything else than a `MyTuple`, that would end in a compilation error…

Comment: Fascinating, you extends the answer to more than I asked.  (but it is exactly what I have to do next)  ..... can't... resist.... copy-paste ...... noo......

Comment: Hey feel free to copy/paste! As long as you understand what's going on under the hood, I'm happy that my code can be useful to people!

Comment: You can also get more info here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Comment: I think your `ConcatLists()` need to be static.

Comment: It's not a member function; it's a global function

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Sorry.

Comment: It's all good! Let me know if there are any other questions you have